# Disable transition after google sign in in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-signin

[FIXED]

When I cancel or sign in with the googleSignIn() method in flutter, there is a transition that I would like to disable because it looks like a black bar falling and I would like to disable it.

The problem looks like this. [Transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWIhL.gif)

This is the code I used for the sign in:

```dart
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

Future<User> googleSignIn() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      //If user canceled the operation
      if (googleUser == null) return null;

      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
      updateUserData(user);
      print("signed in " + user.displayName);
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Something went wrong:\n" + e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Edit:
This problem only happens on android emulations.
When I run it on a physical device, it runs fine.

Comment: Better verify it once on physical device that this really happens.

Comment: That's weird. I think that's due to Google's WebView's status bar. Can you verify it with a different device?

Comment: >Better verify it once on physical device that this really happens
Can confirm this happens on physical device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that its just a glitch in some android emulations, when I tried it on a physical device the transition was not there.

Comment: It does happen on physical devices I tried. Working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63383626/disable-google-sign-in-transition-for-single-screen