# Disable Google Sign in Transition for Single Screen

Tags: android, flutter, animation, firebase-authentication, google-signin

After signing in with the googleSignIn() method in flutter, there is an undesired transition appearing on the screen (Example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWIhL.gif).

This is not a glitch for the Android emulator, it also happens on my physical device.

The only solution I found was to add the following line to the styles.xml to disable the Transition :

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
```

However, I do not want to disable the animations for the whole app. How can I only disable it for the Login Screen ? I do not know what side effects may occur disabling all windowAnimationStyle for the whole app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to create a style for an individual view or a theme for a particular activity or view hierarchy. An example of this is given in the following link: https://gist.github.com/cesarferreira/38bf26a68317ac15f1dc

```
<!-- Developer should create a style -->
<style name="noAnimTheme" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>


<!-- Then in manifest set it as theme for activity or whole application. -->

<activity android:name=".ui.ArticlesActivity" android:theme="@style/noAnimTheme">
</activity>
```

More information on Styles and Themes are given here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#Styles